# Amazon AWS - Hospedar Site

Tags: amazon-aws

Boa tarde, criei um plano na Amazon para usar os recursos de graça por 12 meses.
Hospedei minha aplicação em uma VM windows, contudo não sei como faço para apontar os meus DNS da registro.br do meu dominio para os servidor da Amazon.
Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Você precisa configurar, no registro.br, os endereços do DNS da Amazon. Esses endereços são fornecidos no painel do serviço Route 53 da Amazon. Depois disso, no próprio Route 53, você precisa adicionar um registro do tipo A, por meio do qual você associa uma URL a um endereço IP. Esse é o endereço IP público da instância EC2 que você criou. Na [documentação da Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html) há uma explicação completa.

Comment: Creio eu que vc precisa liberar a porta 80 também;